# JSQMessagesViewController loading from cache

Tags: swift, caching, parse-platform, uicollectionview

I am using `JSQMessagesViewController` with `Parse.com`. I am trying to implement `caching` in the chatController as well.

my cache code looks like this:

```
        if query.hasCachedResult{
        query.cachePolicy = .cacheThenNetwork
        } else{
        query.cachePolicy = .networkOnly
        }
```

Since using `.cacheThenNetwork` I am dealing with the data twice. First from cache, then from Network.

In order to handle this in my `PFQuery.findObjectsInBackground` I use:

```
self.messages.removeAll()
self.users.removeAll()
```

after having found objects.

**The Problem:**
When I reload the data by e.g. pressing the send button.
the `CollectionView`is trying to fetch data, that is not yet downloaded.

```
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!,
    messageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData! {

    return self.messages[indexPath.item]
}
```

Will cause an exception.

How can I make stop the VC from loading the details *before* it finished loading?

The Loading and Adding of messages to the collectionView is implemented from another [Project](https://github.com/huyouare/SwiftParseChat/blob/master/SwiftParseChat/ChatViewController.swift):